# Toggle "PreviewAtlas" with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am working on a plugin which should generate various atlas views based on some parameter. After choosing some variables, the LayoutDesigner should be opened with all the predefined options - this works fine. However, I could not find out, how the "PriviewAtlas" button is toggled with python. So when the Designer starts it should be already activated.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch when a `QgsLayoutDesignerInterface` is opened and if there is a coverage layer, you know you can enable atlas preview

```py
def whenOpenedDesignerInterface(designer):
    if designer.layout().atlas().coverageLayer() is not None:
        designer.setAtlasPreviewEnabled(True)

iface.layoutDesignerOpened.connect(whenOpenedDesignerInterface)
```